# Analog of holomorphic Lefschetz fixed point theorem for smooth algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

If $X$ is a compact complex manifold and $f: X \to X$ is a holomorphic map with isolated nondegenerate zeroes. Then there is a version of Lefschetz fixed point formula with traces on Dolbeaut cohomology
$$
\sum_{f(z)=z} \frac{1}{\det(\operatorname{id}-df(z))}=\sum_q (-1)^q \operatorname{tr}(f^*|H^{0,q}_{\overline{\partial}}(X))
$$
Dolbeaut isomorphism
$$
H^q(X, \Omega^p) \cong H^{p.q}_{\overline{\partial}}(X)
$$
allow us to write the formula in the following way
$$
\sum_{f(z)=z} \frac{1}{\det(\operatorname{id}-df(z))}=\sum_q (-1)^q \operatorname{tr}(f^*|H^{q}(X,\mathcal{O}_X)).
$$
The last formula make sense for, say, smooth projective variety $X$ over algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Two questions: is it still a valid formula for algebraic varieties? Where I can find a proof in such setting?

Comment: Lenny Taelman has [beautiful notes](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/l.d.j.taelman/beijing.pdf) on this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Appendix A in the following notes of Lenny Taelman. He mentions the only published proof of Woods Hole formula: SGA 5, Illusie. But this proof is "rather convoluted," so he gives his own nice and short proof.

https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/l.d.j.taelman/beijing.pdf

Here you will find some explanations about Grothendieck-Serre duality and much more!

Answer (score 1):

This formula is called the Atiyah--Bott fixed point theorem, 
or the Woods Hole fixed point theorem.

My memory is that it is valid for smooth projective (or more generally proper) varieties in
char. $p$ as well (if you think of it as a congruence mod $p$).  But it does need a properness and smoothness
assumption.

P.S.  I think you can find a discussion of it in SGA 4 1/2 .  (This is probably not the optimal reference; but I think it's where I first saw it.  I forget if it is proved there, though, or just described.)

Comment: As far as I understand fixed point formula in SGA $4 1/2$ is for $l-$adic cohomology. Atiyah-Bott theorem is a generalization for elliptic complexes, but still on manifolds.

Comment: @Alex: I'm pretty sure there is a formula in SGA 4 1/2 that deals with etale cohomology with $\mathbb F_p$ coeffs. in char. $p$, and is proved by Artin-Schreier theory and the Woods Hole formula.   That's the discussion I'm thinking of.

Comment: @Alex: Also, what exactly do you mean by "for varieties"?  Do you want a statement that handles the non-smooth case, the non-projective, the char. $p$ case, or what?

Comment: I mean smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, I just want to avoid analytic topology (and Dolbeaut cohomology as a result) and see more algebraic proof. Or the reason way it is not true in such setting.

Comment: @Alex: But the coherent cohomology in your final formula is the same computed algebraically or by complex analytic techniques (such as the Dolbeaut isomorphism), so the statement is certainly true for proj. smooth varieties over  $\mathbb C$.  As for an algebraic *proof*, as I said, I'm pretty sure that the mod $\mathbb F_p$ trace formula in SGA 4 1/2 uses this trace formula in char. $p$, so there must be an alg. proof.